# How can I convince TSServer that I'm using lodash/fp instead of lodash?

Tags: javascript, vim, lodash, youcompleteme, tsserver

- I use [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) in [a personal project](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide), and use Vim to edit and debug that code.
- To have diagnostics and type information, I use [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/#javascript-and-typescript-semantic-completion), which for JavaScript makes use of the [TSServer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/src/server) engine.

Currently, though, several type errors are erroneously detected in my JavaScript files, all boiling down to the engine thinking I'm using "standard" lodash, where the following makes sense,

```js
const a = _.groupBy([], _.isEqual);
```

whereas I'm using lodash/fp, where `_.groupBy` (like many other functions) takes the range argument as the last argument,

```js
const a = _.groupBy(_.isEqual, []);
```

So the former is erroneusly accepted, and the latter is erroneously marked as error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(collection: List<[]>, iteratee?: ValueIteratee<[]>): Dictionary<[][]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(value: any, other: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'List<[]>'.
      Index signature for type 'number' is missing in type '(value: any, other: any) => boolean'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(collection: (value: any, other: any) => boolean, iteratee?: ValueIteratee<never>): Dictionary<never[]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueIteratee<never>'.
      Type '[]' is not assignable to type '[PropertyName, any]'.
        Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 2.
```

I've also asked on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/23532#issuecomment-1019432647), however [the answer](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/23532#issuecomment-1025178892) assumed I was using TypeScript, whereas I just have an HTML file where I'm including lodash/fp from a CDN via a `<script>` tag:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```

How can I convince TSServer that I'm using lodash/fp?

Comment: Could you narrow down the problem a bit? Vim is certainly not involved, here, and YCM is probably only regurgitating TSServer's output.